# replacing values of column of data frame

Tags: r

i am trying to change the values in column Name with VAN with ignoring NA values.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("ABC","VAN","KLA","DCA",  "GOL",NA,   "MNA",NA,   "VAN","BAN",NA,"MHA",NA,"KLA"))


df <- df %>% mutate(Name=replace(.,!is.na(Name),"VAN"))
```

Comment: You need `df %>% mutate(Name=replace(Name,!is.na(Name),"VAN"))`.  i.e. replace the `.` with `Name`

Comment: yes its working , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the OP used `.` and `.` refers to the whole dataset.  We just need to specify the column name 'Name'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(Name=replace(Name,!is.na(Name),"VAN"))
```

-output

```
df
 Name
1   VAN
2   VAN
3   VAN
4   VAN
5   VAN
6  <NA>
7   VAN
8  <NA>
9   VAN
10  VAN
11 <NA>
12  VAN
13 <NA>
14  VAN
```

---

If there are more than one columns, do it with `across` to loop over the columns

```
df <- df %>%
        mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., !is.na(.), "VAN")))
```

Here `everything()` implies all the columns of the dataset

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)


df <- data.frame(Name = c("ABC","VAN","KLA","DCA",  "GOL",NA,   "MNA",NA,   "VAN","BAN",NA,"MHA",NA,"KLA"))

head(df)
#>   Name
#> 1  ABC
#> 2  VAN
#> 3  KLA
#> 4  DCA
#> 5  GOL
#> 6 <NA>

mutate(df, Name = str_replace(Name, "^.*$", 'VAN'))
#>    Name
#> 1   VAN
#> 2   VAN
#> 3   VAN
#> 4   VAN
#> 5   VAN
#> 6  <NA>
#> 7   VAN
#> 8  <NA>
#> 9   VAN
#> 10  VAN
#> 11 <NA>
#> 12  VAN
#> 13 <NA>
#> 14  VAN
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[<-` to assign the value where `Name` is not `NA`.

```
df$Name[!is.na(df$Name)] <- 'VAN'
df
#   Name
#1   VAN
#2   VAN
#3   VAN
#4   VAN
#5   VAN
#6  <NA>
#7   VAN
#8  <NA>
#9   VAN
#10  VAN
#11 <NA>
#12  VAN
#13 <NA>
#14  VAN
```